# convert to date time of the string with T and timezone difference in C#

Tags: datetime

I have one calendar feed which returns date as string as follows

2011-11-10T08:00:00.000-08:00

Now I want to convert this in Date Time of C# object.

How I could do?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Parse("2011-11-10T08:00:00.000-08:00")
```

returns the DateTime object, which to string would be 11/10/2011 4:00:00 PM

Comment: Is DateTime.Parse()  doing subtraction here?

Comment: yup, the last -08:00 means its 8 hours behind UTC

Comment: It is not giving the exact time. For more info it is  RFC 3339 time stamp format.